# Display Looping Input File from database using Laravel on select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a dropdown. I want to show the loop input files from the database by selecting the dropdown.

Detail of the case: if I choose one dropdown, it will show input_file derived from table loop_atachment (doctype column) based on groupid selected.

[image database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCwir.png)

This is my code.

**Dropdown in blade :**

```
<select id="groupid" name="groupid" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1">General</option>
    <option value="2">Golf Club</option>
</select>
```

**Input file should be display here when select dropdown:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">loop attachment</label>
   {{ Form::file('image', array(), null, array('id' => 'image', 'class'=>'form-control'))  }}
</div>
```

**Javascript/ajax :**

```
 $('#groupid').on('change', function(){
    $.post('{{ URL::to('lender/dynamic') }}', {type: 'loop_attachment', id: $('#groupid').val()}, function(e){
        $('#image').html('');
        $('#image').html(e);
        });
    });
```

**Controller :**

```
public function postDynamic(Request $request) 
{
    switch(Input::get('type')):
        case 'loop_attachment':
            $return = '';
            foreach(Loop_attachment::where('groupid', Input::get('id'))->get() as $row) 
                $return .= "$row->doctype <br><input type='file' style='margin-bottom:1px;' name='$row->id' id='image'><br>";
            return $return;
        break;
    endswitch;         
}
```

Currently, does not display any file input when selecting the dropdown, I hope anyone can help me here. Thanks in advance

Comment: "does not display any file input when selecting the dropdown" - Do you have any more info on the issue? Are you sure the AJAX request is being triggered and returned successfully? Check developer tools. Is there a server issue? Is any data returned correctly? Etc :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change my code in question "**Input file should be display here when select dropdown**" become like this:

`<div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label" id="image">loop attachment</label> </div>`

and it works. just need some styling :)